# PHP как вывести текст до двойного переноса строки?

Tags: php, строки, echo

В БД имеется текст, довольно длинный, как, получив весь, текст вывести текст только ДО ДВОЙНОГО переноса строки?

Есть ли какая-нибудь встроенная функция а-ля .IndexOf() в C#?

Comment: Функцией `explode()`. Мануал - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Comment: @mix, большое спасибо, вынеси свой комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функцией `explode()`.

Мануал - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = strtok($input, "\n\n");
```

Но тут зависит от формата перевода строки, может понадобиться и регулярка.